# Displaying integer on toast

Tags: java, android, toast

Im trying to display a toast message with integer inside it
This is how i tried to do it:

```
 Toast.makeText(this,bignum,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But it keeps crash my app.
Thanks for help!

Comment: "Crashes my app" tells us nothing. What exactly happens? What errors are logged? What happened when you debugged?

Comment: Came for  the title, left disappointed.

Comment: @asteri I'm just starting with java, its my second day..

Comment: Even on your second day, we expect you to be able to report what error messages you saw.

Comment: @GalIsrael It was just a joke. :)  Putting Integers on toast, like baked bread.  That's all.  Wasn't a criticism.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Toast.makeText` either takes a `CharSequence` or an `int` as its second argument.

However, the `int` represents **a resource ID** (such as `R.string.hello_world`).

The application crashes probably because no resource is found with that ID, since it's not an ID to start with, but an arbitrary integer.

In your case, use `Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(bignum),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`.

Answer (score 6):

you need a `String`

```
Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(bignum),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

otherwise android will try to look it up for a String with id `bignum`, in your strings.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Try this to "cast" bignum to string:

```
Toast.makeText(this,"" + bignum,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + bignum, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```