# How to create a string resource from an external source?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to access a .php file in the localhost:

```
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try  {
                    System.err.println("It's working ok?");
                    String url = "http://192.168.0.112/hlsystems/api/fetch.php";
                    String charset = "UTF-8";  // Or in Java 7 and later, use the constant: java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()
                    String param1 = "value1";
                    String param2 = "value2";
                    String query = "";

                    try {
                        query = String.format("param1=%s&param2=%s",
                                URLEncoder.encode(param1, charset),
                                URLEncoder.encode(param2, charset));
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    URLConnection connection = null;
                    try {
                        connection = new URL(url + "?" + query).openConnection();
                        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
                        InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
                        System.err.println(response.read());
                        Toast.makeText(mainContext, response.read(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(mainContext, e.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
W/System.err: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x22
```

How am I supposed to previously define a string inside the XML file, if I'm retrieving it from an external source / a webserver?

Full log:

```
W/System.err: 123
W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000022
W/System.err: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x22
W/System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:250)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:268)
W/System.err:     at com.hlsystems.ericsonwillians.saltodepirapora.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:89)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Please post a full log

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace. Also, I would suggest using an http library built for Android rather than raw threads and urlconnection

Comment: Added. Do you mean this isn't done manually? :p I thought that URLConnection *was* the "library".

Comment: Urlconnection is the built in Java class. A library would be Okhttp or Volley

Comment: Also, please don't post curse words in your logging output

Comment: Oh, my bad, forgot about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response.read()` returns an int, a single byte of the response.

You need to convert the stream response to a full String before you Toast it.

The makeText method is overloaded to accept `R.string` resource IDs as a second parameter, which are read only assets, and you cannot create at runtime

If you only care about that one byte, see

[Displaying integer on toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152958/displaying-integer-on-toast)